# Limit to particle emitter size?

Tags: particles

Is there a limit to how small a particle (fluid) emitter can be and still work? I have a character that I want to have a nosebleed with a particle fluid emitter. This means I have to make the emitter fit inside the nostril, which is very small. No matter how I put the settings, the particles are all over the place, and they go beyond the emitter object, making them too big.

Here is a picture of the size in relation to the default grid (the orange dot is the emitter). Is there any way to get a smooth, liquid from this size?
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use particles or a fluid sim? Try particles using [metaballs for the particle object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0WjV6MmCyM).

Comment: I'm using the standard Blender particle system, with the particle type changed from "Newtonian" to "Fluid".

Comment: Fluid physics for particle systems interact with each other, this can lead to particles flying apart when emitted in the same location. They would need to be smaller or one particle at a time.

Comment: How can you make one particle at a time come out?

Comment: One particle at a time means one per frame, you take the number of particles to emit and divide by number of frames. With a start of 1 and end of 200, then emitting 200 particles will give you one per frame, while emitting 400 would give you 2 per frame.